# How to override related field in django?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, orm

Let's say we have such models.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ...
    main_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')

class ProductPhoto(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.photo.url
```

I have two views:

- `ProductsView`. It provides list of products with general information about each one, including `name`, `...`, `main_photo` only.
- `ProductDetailsView`. It provides more detailed info, including **all** photos.

```
class ProductsView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer


class ProductDetailsView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductDetailsSerializer
```

serializers:

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'main_photo')


class ProductDetailsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    photos = StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'main_photo', 'photos')
```

I want detailed view to provide all photos in flat array `photos`, like this `[main_photo, ...rest_photos]`.
In other words,
In response to **detailed** view instead of this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name",
    "main_photo": "/media/photos/main_photo.jpg",
    "photos": [
        "/media/photos/photo1.jpg",
        "/media/photos/photo2.jpg",
        "/media/photos/photo3.jpg"
    ],
}
```

I want to get this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name",
    "photos": [
        "/media/photos/main_photo.jpg",
        "/media/photos/photo1.jpg",
        "/media/photos/photo2.jpg",
        "/media/photos/photo3.jpg"
    ],
}
```

How can I do this with django rest framework? On which level should this logic be implemented? Model, View, Serializer?

I think it should be somewhere here, but not quite sure how should it look.

```py
class ProductDetailsView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductDetailsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set = Product.objects.all()
        # ...
        return query_set
```

Comment: Hey, can you add an example. Use both the models and mention what you expect the output to be. It will be easier to suggest.

Comment: @JyothiS, just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For url of the photos add a `__str__` method in `ProductPhoto` which will return only url of the photo

```py
class ProductPhoto(models.Model):
...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.photo.url
```

and change `ProductDetailsSerializer` like this

```py
class ProductDetailsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    photo_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_photo_list(self, obj):
        db_photos = obj.photos.all()
        result = []
        if obj.main_photo:
            result.append(obj.main_photo.url)
        for p in db_photos:
            result.append(p.photo.url)
        return result   


    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'photo_list')
```

For more relation related documentation for DRF [check this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Comment: Thank you. It simplifies serializer part actually. I add it both in my code and question here.
But this is not my question about.